# Filter arraylist by multiple variables in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

This is a part of my project and I can't find out any way to implement this.

So I have an `ArrayList` of Student class. Here is the class:

```
public abstract class Student {
  protected int STT;
  protected int Nhom;
  protected int To;
  protected String HoLot;
  protected String Ten;
  protected String Lop;
  protected String Khoa;
}
```

I want to filter that list and return another `ArrayList` hold elements that match some value of the class. My project right now just can filter only one attribute at a time.

[image: Image 1]

What I have done is just switch the index of selected item (combobox) and check with all elements in the list.

But what I actually want is that user can choose many variables they want to filter the list and we don't know how many that they choose.

[image: Image 2]

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Filtering by itself isn't too challenging. Simply create a helper method to do the filtering for you:

If Java 8 is allowed (and you've learned it):

```
public static void filter(ArrayList<Student> lst, Predicate<Student> acceptStudent) {
    ArrayList<Student> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Student s : lst) {
        if (acceptStudent.test(s)) {
            lst2.add(s);
        }
    }
    return lst2;
}
```

Without Java 8 it gets a lot more verbose, but is essentially the same

```
public static void filter(ArrayList<Student> lst, boolean testSST, int requiredSST, 
                          boolean testNhom, int requiredNHom, boolean testTo, 
                          int requiredTo, boolean testHoLot, String requiredHoLot,
                          boolean testTen, String requiredTen, boolean testLop,
                          String requiredLop, boolean testKhoa, String requiredKhoa) {
    ArrayList<Student> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Student s : lst) {
        if ((!testSST || s.SST == requiredSST) && 
            (!testNHom || s.Nhom == requiredNHom) && 
            (!testTo || s.To == requiredTo) && 
            (!testHoLot || Objects.equals(s.NHom, requiredHoLot)) &&
            (!testTen || Objects.equals(s.Ten, requiredTen)) && 
            (!testLop || Objects.equals(s.Lop, requiredLop)) &&
            (!testKhoa || Objects.equals(s.Khoa, requiredKhoa))) {

            lst2.add(s);
        }
    }
    return lst2;
}
```

Then simply hook the gui up to the filter method, feed in acceptable arguments, and off you go!

Comment: What does the acceptStudent.test(s) function do? it will test all the object attributes? do you have some documents to this?

Comment: You'd have to assemble a predicate that takes a student object and returns true if it's valid

Comment: so i have to create predicates for all case? example that user choose 1, 2 ,3, 4 ... attributes to filter?